# How to add React components based on conditional statements evaluating a boolean based on a changable counter

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, conditional-rendering

Good morning,

I am attempting to add `React` components based on a counter value and then use conditional statements to determine whether or not they are rendered.  In other words, I want to add components below a component when a "+" is clicked and then remove those elements when an "x" is clicked.  The code I am attempting to use is as follows:

```
let differentials = 0;

const diffAdded = () => {
    if (differentials < 2) {
        differentials++;
    }
}

const diffRemoved = () => {
    if (differentials > 0) {
       differentials--;
    }
}
    return (
        <article className="addJob">
            <header className="margin title">
                <p>Add new job:</p>
            </header>
            <main>
                <form>
                    <section className="form-group">
                        <label className="margin" htmlFor="name">Job name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" className="form-control anInput"                 
                             placeholder="Enter job title" required />
                        <label className="margin" htmlFor="hourly">Hourly rate</label>
                        <input type="number" id="hourly" className="form-control anInput" 
                             placeholder="$##.##" required />
                    </section>
                    <section>
                        <label className="margin">Shift/night differential?</label>
                        <i className="fa fa-plus add-button margin" aria-hidden="true" onClick={() =>     
                                                                            diffAdded()}></i>
                    </section>

                    //this section is the one I want to changed based on counter value
                    <section>
                        {differentials > 0  && <DiffSection id="diff1" diffRemoved={() =>     
                                                                        diffRemoved()}/>}
                        {differentials > 1 && <DiffSection id="diff2" diffRemoved={() =>                             
                                                                        diffRemoved()}/>}
                    </section>
                    <section className="submit-button" onClick={() => jobAdded(
                        document.getElementById('name'),
                        document.getElementById('hourly'),
                        document.getElementById('diff1'),
                        document.getElementById('diff2')
                    )
                }>
                    <p>Submit</p>
                </section>
            </form>
        </main>
        <section className="footer" onClick={() => nameClicked()}>
            <span className="user-name">{props.userData.name}</span>
        </section>
    </article>
    );
}
```

I have attempted this same thing by instantiating an empty array and then pushing the  component when the "+" icon is clicked.

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do in code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-mountain-rll71?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing local variables does not trigger component's lifecycle, that can be done by using React API like `useState`.

That's basic concepts of React, you should refer to [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), [Component State](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html).

```
export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const plusClicked = () => {
    if (counter < 2) {
      setCounter(p => p + 1);
      console.log(counter);
    }
  };

  const minusClicked = () => {
    if (counter > 0) {
      setCounter(p => p - 1);
      console.log(counter);
    }
  };

return (...)
}
```

[image: Edit crazy-cookies-2jb2e]